# Visual Studio Installer Projects with PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, database, winforms, postgresql

I'm starting a Windows Form C # project, a business application that the user downloads, installs, and uses without any complications. Is it possible to do Visual Studio Installer Projects to install PostgreSQL together with the application? The installation must proceed without any interaction with the user.

Comment: x-posted as https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/94042

Comment: google "postgresql embedded application" ?

Comment: What's the problem with asking in multiple languages?

Comment: No problem. I'm posting a link so people who find this question know to look at the other. If it's answered there, it will help others who find it here, at least if they can read spanish. Please post cross-reference link there to here too.

Comment: OK thank you! I changed the question to be clearer!

Comment: Also x-posted to https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227970/14847 . Kindly make links on those two back to here please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bundle the PostgreSQL binaries in your app, but not embed them into the same process. You will need to invoke `initdb`, `pg_ctl`, etc in your app, and manage postgres startup and shutdown.

It works well, but can be fiddly.

Please *do not* use the default port 5432 or bundle the official postgres installer and run it in silent mode. This confuses users *a lot* when they wonder where "postgres" came from and they come yelling on the mailing lists about our "adware" or "stealth install" or whatever. Instead, bundle the binaries from the .zip, a precompiled install tree, or whatever. And *do not* run on port 5432.

Rememember to bundle the MSVC runtime for the postgres binaries you're using, if they need a different one to your app.

There's lots of advice out there on how to do this in more detail.

Comment: Thank you very much @CraigRinger! I did exactly as you said, I created an app server with windows form where your function is to manage database service: start, stop, restart and configurations like port, remote access.